# Not seeing Boot order change Option

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop and its giving me real stomachaches! Windows 10 is in UEFI mode. So I have to install Ubuntu also in UEFI mode. As such, I disabled Fastboot in Win 10, and SecureBoot in UEFI/BIOS. I created a Ubuntu bootable pendrive using YUMI software(pendrivelinux.com).

The biggest problem I'm facing now is, I'm unable to change the Boot Order Sequence. In fact, I'm not even seeing the option to change the boot order. My laptop doesn't have a CD-DVD Drive, so it's alright that I'm not seeing the boot from DVD option. But USB?

[UEFI/BIOS images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D9r.jpg) taken through my mobile:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D9r.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D9r.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D9r.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D9r.jpg]

Please help me here. I dearly want to install and use Linux alongside Win 10. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can press F12 at the "Dell" logo to get the boot menu, can't you?

Comment: I did and that is how I got the images of my laptop's UEFI/BIOS screens. Kindly see the Imgur link.

Comment: Had you searched the web for the meaning of the items in the `Boot` menu, Dwell would have told you that `Add Boot Option` might be worth a look.

Comment: I think @grawity's comment relates to the ad-hoc option of choosing a device to boot from at system start, which is different from entering the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not use YUMI. It's been a while since I've done anything with it, but I've seen a lot of problem reports that suggest it doesn't create EFI-bootable disks. [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) and [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) both seem to do a better job on this score.

I also recommend you leave Secure Boot enabled, at least initially. Ubuntu *should* work with Secure Boot enabled, although there are some broken computers on which it doesn't work. If you have problems booting the installer, you might consider disabling Secure Boot, but as it will probably work, I recommend disabling it as a backup plan. Note that if you get as far as GRUB, much less an actually-booting kernel or Ubuntu logo, Secure Boot is not a problem. Also, when people disable Secure Boot, they also sometimes enable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot" support). This is a Bad Idea, as detailed on [my page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Most EFI-based computers provide a built-in boot manager. You typically access it by hitting a function key (usually F8 or higher) as you power on the computer. If this works, you should be able to select the Ubuntu boot disk on a boot-by-boot basis. (Be sure to select the entry with "UEFI" in the description, if there are two for your device.) If you don't see an entry for your device, then that suggests that it was prepared incorrectly. Try another tool or review the options in the tool you used. (Rufus, for instance, provides several options that can affect how likely a medium is to boot on different computers.)

Answer (score 0):

On your boot tab, what are the other options for "Boot List Options", if there is nothing there, what do you get when you "Add Boot Option", it looks like you may be able to add USB from there.  As Rod said, look for the FXX buttons on boot.  Usually F12 for Dell's that I've seen.

I have never had success with Secure Boot on, usually doesn't let me boot to anything but the current OS.